# How to prevent "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currenlty working on a TS3 query bot written in node.js.
I added an auto reconnect to it but I have the issue now that the bot crashes if the server is offline with the following error:

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:983:19)
```

The line which starts the connection is the following:

```
var cl = new ts3.TeamSpeakClient(config.serverIP);
```

used with the node-ts api -> https://github.com/nikeee/node-ts

I already added the following events:

```
cl.on('error', function(err){
    console.log("bla: " + err)
});
cl.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

uncaughtException doesn't get triggered and error doesn't prevent the crash.

How can I prevent it from crashing?

Edit: It's async btw.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the UncaughtException on the process rather than in ts3 object.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

More on handling exceptions can be found over [here](http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/).

UPDATE:

cl has its own fail promise as well. To be implemented like this:

```
cl.fail(function(err) {
    console.log("An error occurred." + util.inspect(err))
});
```

Comment: isn't process depreciated and only works in sync places?

Comment: 1. Error get logged but still crashes.
2. "fail" is not defined error.

I forgot to add that it is async.

Comment: @user2693017: It is not deprecated and can be used today as well, and it does not depend on sync places either.

Comment: @SirWill: .fail I took from the documentation which you only pointed out. It will crash as you are just logging the error and not respawning the process. The link which i gave in the error, gives you a way to respawn the process. To respawn you can always used forever module