# Server Changes on an Ionic Project

Tags: node.js, express, server

I am simply a beginner at NodeJs. I have a client's Ionic project.
He has sent me
Server Access FTP:
IP, user and pass

and has said, if any server side changes then to be done on server. 
app.js file for socket and server side component is in /usr/www

Now i can't find any 'app.js' consisting of node commands in the project. There is an app.js in www/ directory but there is not node command inside. How to access server and where to use the IP, user, pass.
Please explain if you know the answer. Considering me totally nil at node.js and express.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-ftp as a FTP client. It is a module for node.js which will provide an interface to communicate with the FTP server. You can refer this link to get more information about [node-ftp](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp).

Comment: where to use IP, user & password?

Comment: You can use IP, user and password in connection.js file. I have already provided the reference link from which you can get overall idea about that.

Comment: getting this on running the file consisting of code given in 'Get a directory listing of the current (remote) working directory
events.js:85
   throw: er; // Unhandled.....

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: Mohammad, refer this thread for your error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340379/how-to-prevent-error-connect-econnrefused.